# Windows XP machine doesn't see Debian disk in VirtualBox

Tags: windows-xp, hard-drive, virtualbox, debian

I have created a test Windows XP machine for testing software. I also have an old Debian HDD. But I have forgotten my Debian password (it last ran 2 years ago). I think I'll either reset the password or back-up my source codes and install new debian. For either, I need to access the `debian.vhd` file externally and get files or [reset the password](http://www.debianadmin.com/forgot-root-password-or-reset-root-password-in-debian.html).

I thought I could add the drive to my windows machine:

[image: image description]

But when I run the windows machine, there's no second HDD:

[image: image description]

Though in Device manager, I can clearly see two hardware drives:

[image: image description]

So what am I doing wrong? Should I install the drive somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot access the disk because linux OSs use the ext filesystem which Windows cannot natively read. Your best bet would be to install another linux OS on you virtualbox then attach the debian disk to the new linux OS. Or if you really want to access it via Winodws then you'll have to install special software to do so.

Comment: Ah... well, that explains why this trick didn't work either: http://www.howtogeek.com/51174/mount-and-unmount-a-vhd-file-in-windows-explorer-via-a-right-click/